# how do you get c++ Intellisense data in a visual Studio Extention?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am making a Visual Studio c++ 2010 extension.  I was wondering if there was some way to get intellisense data. like, perhapse the scope of where the caret is. class member variable and function names, function parameters ect.

all I've found atm is Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense namespace, but it doesn't seem to give low level direct access to the data? seems more like a bunch of filtering functions?

I basically want to do my own auto complete, but I don't want to have to parse all the code when intellisense is doing a good job of that already...

EDIT:

ok, so the 2010 intellisense data base file is just an sql database file now, I opened it with sql server 2008 express, and had a look through, it seems to have all the types of data I'm looking for, and I should hopefully be able to access it through code.

the only thing is, I would much rather access the in memory database loaded (and presumably, constantly updated) by intellisense, so that I get all the updates in real time, and don't have to load stuff off the disk.

so, anyone know how to access the database loaded by intellisense from an extension?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the direct answer to access intellisense database.  But, I remember Alvin Chardon wrote a nice article about data flow diagram of VC++ intellisense.  The link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379615%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) may be useful to this question.