# Access source code information from the Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to get into creating Visual Studio extensions. There are a few examples in the online documentation from Microsoft about creating custom stuff but I can't find anything on how to access Intellisense (or any other code analysis).

I know there are some questions about this topic (namely [how do you get c++ Intellisense data in a visual Studio Extention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104284/how-do-you-get-c-intellisense-data-in-a-visual-studio-extention)) but those are from 2012 or earlier and not up to date anymore (at least I hope so).

The following is only applied to C++ source code.

What I specifically want, is to examine the expression that the cursor is at. Then I want to check whether the expression is either

- an object declaration / instanciation, like `string s("my string");`, or
- a function call, like `std::max(1, 2);`

From those expressions I want to get the full qualified name (including the namespace) of the type / function and possibly the types of the function / constructor arguments. For example:

```
// ...
using namespace std;
auto x = max(1, 2);
// ...
```

Now, if the cursor enters `max` I need the full qualified name `::std::max` and the argument types `[int, int]`.

Another example:

```
// ...
using namespace std;
string s("my string");
// ...
```

Here I need the full qualified name `::std::string` and the argument types `[const char*, std::allocator]`.

Is this somehow possible? I'm also interested in partial solutions. Any guidance or hints to some sort of documentation is very welcome.

Comment: Display as [quick info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453937/show-tooltip-on-hover-over-text/57614982#57614982)?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT My problem is not displaying things, but accessing intellisense data.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I originally thought maybe we can try to get current variable and then recognize it to display info, after check it's a bad and complex idea.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Problem is, I need the full type name. If someone uses `using namespace xyz;` somewhere in the code or a macro instead I can't get away with just looking at the text.

Comment: Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379615(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and we will try to implement a sample and share it here(It may take some time).

Comment: Hi friend,  is it possible that it's an X Y problem, maybe what you want to do is not getting intelligence data. Instead, what you want is to implement an intelligence provider just like the implementation in [sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1216579/Implementing-Custom-XAML-Intellisense-VS-Extension).

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT It's not an XY problem. I need the data described in the question. Reason is, if I can get a full type name or function signature I can look that type / function up on cppreference and display the description in a quick info, because Microsoft doesn't ship a documentation for the C++ standard library.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Could the answer below makes some help?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT The answer might be helpful from what I've read but I don't have the time to continue this project atm. Maybe I find some free time on the weekend. Regardless, I will report back as soon as I make progress.

Answer (score 1):

We can only get partial information via code model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vccodemodel.vccodemodel?view=visualstudiosdk-2017